# "Ele vamos para a praia" está correto?

Tags: gramática, concordância-verbal, concordância, semântica

As conjugações verbais no plural, excetuando-se as da terceira pessoa (ex.: *souberam*), implicam um pronome como sujeito.

No caso da primeira pessoa do plural (ex.: *vamos*), a conjugação implica que o falante fez a ação; por exemplo, em “Maria disse *fomos para o mercado*”, Maria foi para o mercado, independentemente de ter ido com outrem ou al. No caso da segunda pessoa do plural (ex.: *sois*), implica-se a participação do audiente; por “Carlos disse a João: *vós me comprastes uma roupa de natal!*”, temos certeza de que João comprou uma roupa.

Por isso veio a dúvida: como essas duas conjugações implicam um sujeito específico (*ides* implica *vais*, *somos* implica *sou*), será que as seguintes frases estão corretas gramaticalmente?

1. *João vamos para praia*, que seria igual a *João e eu vamos para praia*;
2. *Carlinhos gostais disso*, que seria igual a *Carlinhos e tu gostais disso*.

Ou ainda:

3. *Maria nos abraçamos no jogo*, que seria igual a *Maria e eu nós abraçamos no jogo*;
4. *Eles vos pareceis bastante*, que seria igual a *eles e tu vos pareceis bastante*.

Answer (score 1):

Não, não está correto.

Um pressuposto da pergunta está também errado.

> No caso da primeira pessoa do plural (ex.: vamos), a conjugação implica que o falante fez a ação; por exemplo, em “Maria disse fomos para o mercado”, Maria foi para o mercado, independentemente de ter ido com outrem ou al

Primeiro, falta-ta aí um *que*. O correto é:

> A Maria disse que fomos para o mercado.

Segundo, o que te está a escapar nesta frase é que ela composta por duas orações, orações essas que têm sujeitos distintos. O sujeito da oração matriz é *a Maria*, com o qual *disse* (3.ª pessoa do singular) concorda; a oração encaixada *fomos para o mercado* tem o sujeito omisso *nós* (que inclui necessariamente o falante e pelo menos mais uma pessoa, salvo exceções que não vale a pena cobrir). Neste *nós* pode ou não estar incluída a Maria.

> No caso da segunda pessoa do plural (ex.: sois), implica-se a participação do audiente; por “Carlos disse a João: vós me comprastes uma roupa de natal!”, temos certeza de que João comprou uma roupa.

Neste caso sim, o João (o interlocutor) e mais alguém (interlocutor ou não) compraram roupa. Aqui *vós* é o sujeito de *comprar*.

> João vamos para praia, que seria igual a João e eu vamos para praia;
> ...

Nenhuma destas frases está correta. A flexão do verbo não pode implicar um sujeito distinto daquele que está expresso (quando muito temos coisas como *eu parece-me*, que é abordado noutra pergunta; em todo o caso *eu* não é aí sujeito de *parecer*). Tens de dizer *eu e o João* ou algo do género.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas acho que não entendeste o que a Maria disse, está em itálico em vez de entre aspas. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

> Eles vos pareceis bastante

Esta frase é enganadora por várias razões, por exemplo:

> A eles vos pareceis bastante.

ou

> Pareceis-vos bastante a eles.

O problema é que a falta do artigo definido `a` (ou seja, um determinante) não deixa entender que o pronome `eles` é complemento directo do verbo.

> O *artigo definido* é, em geral, um mero designativo. Anteposto a um substantivo comum, serve para determiná-lo, ou seja, para apresentá-lo isolado dos outros indivíduos ou objectos (...)
>
> in *"Nova gramática do português contemporáneo"*, Lindley Cintra e Celso Cunha.

A razão pela qual o exemplo das frases acima não dispensa o determinante é porque o verbo **"parecer"** é transitivo, para ter o seu significado completo precisa de um objecto - que neste caso sem artigo definido não fica claramente determinado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Será que não é preposição "a"? Posso estar errado.

Comment: @Schilive é preposição sim, enganei-me. Quando tiver um bocado de paciência eu edito a postagem para corrigir.

Comment: @bsd_coder, obrigado.